# Correct way to redirect multiple domains on one host - NGINX

Tags: nginx

In this example I have 4 websites on 2 different CMS's and 5 different domains.

`a.com` `sub.a.com` `b.com` `c.com` are on CMS1
`d.com` is on CMS2

`http` should redirect to `https`
`a.com` `www.a.com` `www.sub.a.com`  to `sub.a.com`
`www.b.com` to `b.com`
`www.c.com` to `c.com`
`www.d.com` to `d.com`

Each domain has their own separate website which is handled by their common CMS. For example, this means that even though `b.com` and `c.com` use the same CMS, admin panel and root directory; the pages which are served frontend are completely different. This functionality is handled by the CMS.

Due to this configuration I have 2 .conf files for NGINX, one for domains a-c and one for d.

Here comes the problem. Below is what I have come up with so far but doesn't work the way I have outlined above. Domains `www.a.com`-`www.c.com` seem to all redirect to `sub.a.com`. `www.sub.a.com` doesn't redirect to `sub.a.com`. Am I looking at this all wrong?

**a.com.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name a.com www.a.com sub.a.com www.sub.a.com b.com www.b.com c.com www.c.dom;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.a.com www.sub.a.com;
  return 301 https://sub.a.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.b.com;
  return 301 https://b.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.c.com;
  return 301 https://c.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name a.com sub.a.com b.com c.com;
  root /srv/a.com/www;
  include snippets/ssl-a.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  # REST OF CONFIG
}
```

**d.com.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name d.com www.d.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.d.com;
  return 301 https://d.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name d.com;
  root /srv/d.com/www;
  include snippets/ssl-d.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  # REST OF CONFIG
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `$host` rather than `$server_name` if you want `nginx` to pick the name that was used to make the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for more.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.com www.a.com sub.a.com www.sub.a.com b.com www.b.com c.com www.c.dom;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This is perhaps good advice but did not resolve any of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

In the HTTP virtual server section, I would always use the final domain as the redirect destination.

For example, now when a request comes into `http://www.b.com`, it will redirect to `https://www.b.com` and then to `https://b.com`, causing two redirects for the client until he reaches the ultimate destination. However, to accomplish this, one needs to use a regular expression for the `server_name` and use its captured value in the redirect, for example like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?:www)?\.(<domain>.+)\.com$;
    return 301 https://$domain.com;
}
```

This regular expression will capture everything between `www.` prefix and `.com` suffix into $1, or if `www.` prefix does not exist, then everything before `.com`. `$1` is then used as the redirect destination.

Another issue with your configuration is the request to `http://www.a.com`. The first redirect will go to `https://www.a.com`, which will redirect it to `https://sub.a.com`, because the second `server` block matches that domain.

Comment: How would this work taking into account `d.com` which has its own separate config? In your example, the config for `a.com` would also affect `d.com` even though it's not directly referenced. Perhaps one does not want `www.d.com` to redirect to `non-www` or `https`.

Comment: It does not affect the operation of `d.com`. nginx first searches for exact matches for `server_name`, then longest wildcard match starting with asterisk, then longest wildcard match ending with asterisk and finally regular expressions.

Comment: I changed the regular expression into a named variable, since nginx documentation only explicitly refers to named variable captures working in `server_name` directive.